# Convert Ajax POST script to PHP cURL POST Script

Tags: php, ajax, curl, post

I'm trying to make a post call like this to return a jwt bearer token. But in php using cURL. So I can save the bearer token to a variable for use in the API calls.

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'http://www.your-site.com/siteguard/api/prepare-public-jwt',
  data: { api_key: 'YOUR_PUBLIC_API_KEY' },
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function (data) {
    //Returns encoded JWT
    console.log(data);
  }
});
```

Php Code Im using

```
 $url = $this->getTokenUrl();

        $curl = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

        $headers = array(
            "Content-Type: application/json",
        );
        
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

        $data = ["api_key" => "xOMjVpz83rxDKjJUX9qNClB2BwadcRWjm09YSCdasdabdasdasdasdgTR8fuvR7jQHP8ZVpbOOmdXqKEt0AVX"];

        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

        //for debug only!
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

        $resp = curl_exec($curl);
        curl_close($curl);
        var_dump($resp);
```

The Return is this

```
{"code":401,"status":"error","response":"Invalid Public API key","link":"http:\/\/localhost\/siteguard\/api\/prepare-public-jwt"}"
```

Comment: 1. Download postman, and create the post with all its required settings. 2. Click the `Code` button, located (in Windows) on the top right corner (about 2PM from the SEND button) 3. Select the desired programming language (PHP- cURL in your case). 4. ??? 5. Profit!

Comment: Have you confirmed that the token returns using Javascript? It may be an issue with your Siteguard install.

Comment: Also, try `json_encode($data)` before `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);`

Comment: @mulquin it does return the token using the java in the console. Will try it now and return with the results

Comment: did not work, it still returns the same error.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to achieve it use this

```
        $url = $this->getTokenUrl();

        $curl = curl_init();

        curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
            CURLOPT_URL => $url,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
            CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
            CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
            CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
            CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => 'xOMjVpz83rxDKjJUX9qNClB2BwadcRWjm09YSCdasdabdasdasdasdgTR8fuvR7jQHP8ZVpbOOmdXqKEt0AVX',
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
              'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            ),
          ));
          
          $response = curl_exec($curl);
          $obj = json_decode($response);

          curl_close($curl);

          return $obj->response;
```